# Android Dagger2 field not injected

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

So basicly am trying to use dagger to inject a `Baz` field into class `Foo`,  it goes like this

**Baz.java**

```
public class Baz { 

}
```

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo {
   @Inject Baz baz;
}
```

but nothing gets injected and `baz` still null when i run it, i even tried to write the `Baz` empty `constructor` and annotate it with `@Inject` but it doesn't work either

how dagger work is it able to see all my classes so when i request a class instance he can create one, or am i missing some annotation, or even worse my annotation processor not working. i added those dependencies to my `app.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
```

Comment: The annotation itself can't magically inject into `baz`. You have to write a provider (`@Provides`) in your module (`@Module`) and a Component (`@Component`) to glue your injection and module together.

Comment: @dipdipdip thanks i tried that also didn't work, in the documentation's `User Guide` they say that `@Provides` is for awkward initialization and configurable classes and my simple `@Inject` should work for those `empty constructor` simple classes

Comment: I don't understand reason of 2 downvotes. I think if people don't see much code in question they automatically downvote. Btw, you have great answer below, that explains how Dagger works.

Comment: @MishaAkopov thank you a down vote without explanation is not useful, they should make down voting at 100 reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inject something somewhere using `Dagger2`, it's essential to have a `component`, also you need a place, where you want to have `Foo` object (which has a `Baz` object itself). In addition to this, you should specify the way, how objects should be created by `dagger2`. In your case constructor injection is absolutely OK.

Let's assume, that our `component` is `TestComponent` and the place, where we want to have `Foo` object is `MainActivity`, then the code would be something like this:

`Baz.java`

```
public class Baz {

    @Inject
    public Baz() {
    }
}
```

`Foo.java`

```
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    Baz baz;

    @Inject
    public Foo() {
    }
}
```

`TestComponent.java`

```
@Component
public interface TestComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity injector);
}
```

(When you create `component`, rebuild the project)

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    Foo foo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DaggerTestComponent.builder().build().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot  i followed your example and I've noticed that the class `DaggerTestComponent` (or any component i define) are not generated, am using `Android studio 3.0` with `gradle version 4.1`, it seems to me that the annotation are not being resolved by dagger at all any tips

Comment: Did you rebuild the project after creation of TestComponent.java file ?

Comment: If you have this line in your `build.gradle(Module:app)`

`annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'` 

then check, if you have enabled annotation processor for the project:

*Preferences > Build, Exection, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors > Check "Enable annotation processing"*

Comment: thanks a lot that helped the component class now is being generated in my app code, i was testing it in a `JUnit test` and until now it still not generating there i added those line either
`testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1`
`testImplementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'`